# Do I need to return an object from a method if I'm modifying it?

Tags: java

Say I have code

```
if(some statement){
   object1.setSomeField("abc");
}
```

Could I do this?

```
    public void methodToSetField(SomeObject object1){
       //provide some logic for setting
       object1.setSomeField("abc")
    }

   if(some statement){
      this.methodToSetField(object1);
   }
```

Now my question is, 
if I want to replace the first piece of code, with the method do I need to return object1 or is it enough to set it.

Comment: you dont need to return that object

Comment: no. you need not to return.

Comment: you know you can run it and test .... see if it works

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You never *have* to return a value unless the method declares a return type. Whether or not you *should* return a value friends on how you want to use the method. Also, even if a method *does* return a value, you can ignore the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fine to do. In java, when you pass in an object, you don't actually pass in the "object" but rather the reference (or pointer) to the object.

Any modifications you make will directly alter the object you've passed in as long as you don't do something like:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
```

**EDIT:** [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 6):

No you don't have to , as you are working on the same memory object. So the calling code, if uses the values after calling your method, it should see the updates.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the  reference of `object1` ,So no need to return it.It changes.

See the code below:

```
  public void methodToSetField(SomeObject object1){
       //provide some logic for setting
       object1.setSomeField("abc")
    }
```

And this

```
 public object1Type  methodToSetField(SomeObject object1){
           //provide some logic for setting
           object1.setSomeField("abc");
           return object1;
        }
```

In both the cases ,After you execute the code `object1` updates.

So bottem line is,Not need to `return`.

Comment: Not that again :) Passing a reference by value

Comment: @Matthias Yeah,Biggest confusion ever. :)

Comment: Hopefully only for the beginners.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, since you are passing the copy of the address location of the object referenced when you dealing with the same object.